# What type of wire to use for an overhead drop. For Fire Alarm system?

Tags: wiring, smoke-detectors

Type of wire needed? It seems to be a #14, 3 wire SO cord which was not the correct wire to use it has broken down in the sunlight. The insulation is brittle and it some places removed.

Comment: How far does this wire run, and is there a messenger wire (bare steel wire) between the two buildings already?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Yeah, I think a photo failed to attach.  Here, you [edit] your question to add detail.   If you want to log in from a different device or browser to add photos, then register your account first (tie it to an email/password, google, or facebook).